# 3d Models are not properly showing by the "flutter_cube: ^0.0.4" in flutter

Tags: flutter, 3d, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

It is not showing proper **3d models** it shows only the  **`shadow`** of the models. How I am wrong or How it will show the same models?
**Both pictures are here**
real model png
[image]

while .obj file load it shows like this.

[image]

**3d files is here**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cube/flutter_cube.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late Object jet;

  @override
  void initState() {
    jet = Object(fileName: "assets/model/odb.obj");

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text("Flutter 3D"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Cube(
                onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
                  scene.world.add(jet);
                  scene.camera.zoom = 8;
                },
              ),
            ),
            // Expanded(
            //   child: Cube(
            //     onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
            //       scene.world.add(jet);
            //       scene.camera.zoom = 10;
            //     },
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used "flutter_cube" yestoday,it worked very well.But it can't load the normal_mapping image about obj files.
I think you can try new version of flutter_cube(0.1.1),just use the code below:

```
Cube(
      onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
        scene.world.add(Object(fileName: 'assets/cube/cube.obj'));
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Textures weren't showing. First thing was I didn't have `lighting = true` in Object, whil adding it in scene. But after I added multiple objects, textures didn't show correctly. They were overriding each others. So I explicitly loaded texture for each object (eg `objectName.mesh.texture = loadedTexture`) and after that it works.